# search one or all

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

I have a SQL table with two columns:

```
Name  Number    
A     0  
C     1         
B     2  
C     3
```

I want to use LINQ to search on name (ONE or ALL)

in another words: this function: `Search("C")`. Would give the following result:

```
C1
C3
```

or
Search(ALL).
Result:

```
A   0  
C   1  
B   2  
C   3
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: What is the data structure you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it is very unclear why would you search for something that you know wont restrict anything, returning the whole set of records.

So, if you want to know how to search for a specific name using LINQ, look this:

```
public class NameObject
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int Number { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
     List<NameObject> names = new List<NameObject>();

     names.Add(new NameObject(){ Name="A", Number = 1});
     names.Add(new NameObject(){ Name="B", Number = 1});
     names.Add(new NameObject(){ Name="B", Number = 2});
     names.Add(new NameObject(){ Name="C", Number = 1});
     names.Add(new NameObject(){ Name="C", Number = 2});

     var searchResult = names.Where(x=> x.Name == "C");
}
```

Additionally, if you are using DataTable, you could just:

```
DataRow[] searchResult = table.Select("name = 'C'");
```